# Python Social Auth - User is authenticated with facebook but cannot access pages

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-social-auth

I have an issue with Facebook authentication with Python Social Auth.

I have login with Facebook, Google and Twitter.

After login, I redirect the user to my dashboard at /user/dashboard with the use of login_redirect decorator. While it works fine with Google and Twitter, I am not able to redirect the user authenticated with Facebook.

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    user = ""
    if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
        user = AuthUser.objects.get(id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
    template = 'user/index.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

In Settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '******'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '*******'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_location']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'locale': 'en_US',
    'fields': 'id, name, email, age_range, about, picture, location'
}
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_VERSION = '2.10'
```

When I remove the login_required decorator, the user is redirected to the dashboard. But when the user tries to go to another page, there django says user is not authenticated. Is this an issue with the Facebook API or the application?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Stuck with same problem. Did you find any solution to this.  What i see is that the logged in user is set to Anonymous before the redirect. The login required decorator just catches that. If you redirect to a page which does not require a login, the redirect works , but the user is still Anonymous !!

Comment: Nope, I removed Facebook login for the moment. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check [`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`](https://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#authentication-backends). Facebook authentication backend must be in this list.

2) Cleanup cookies and check that facebook user [is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) on you site.

Comment: I have 'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2' in my AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. The user is active, and i did cleanup cookies. That's the reason I am stumped by this.

Comment: Try to downgrade facebook api version to '2.9' and check server logs for erros

Comment: Tried both, didn't get anywhere. I am sorry I have nothing that I can actually show.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty fix. I didn't look at all possible scenarios. This answer can be improved. First step is to get rid of the login required decorator from the redirect view. Then use the following code in the view

```
if request.user.is_anonymous():
    # check if user logged in through facebook, csrf token will be validated by the middleware
    if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
        auth_user_id = request.session['_auth_user_id']
        user_obj = User.objects.filter(id=auth_user_id)
        request.user = user_obj[0]
        userProfile = model_to_dict(user_obj[0])
    else:
        # redirect user to login page
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to update your app permission to provide the desired pieces of information(including email).
Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, select your app and the permission you want to provide. Then generate a new test access token.